# Selenium WebDriver, TestNG - Couldn't run test via Jenkins "g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed"

Tags: java, maven, firefox, selenium, jenkins

I've Maven project with TestNG class which contains only one test for Firefox Browser. All works fine when I run this suite from IDE or terminal (mvn install).
Error occurs after attempt to run it via Jenkins locally (http://localhost:8080).

```
Running TestSuite
```

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
(process:28573): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: 0:0

```
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:275)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
at example.Home.beforeTest(Home.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:177)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 47.19 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   beforeTest(example.Home): Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7056; process output follows: (..)

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of reasons:

- no Firefox installed on Jenkins box
- no x server running on Jenkins box
- Firefox version not supported by this version of selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not the g_slice_set_config, but rather the "Error: Cannot open display"

to get that fixed you need to properly setup a headless testing environment for your Jenkins. Try following this for a start and hopefully you will be fine (;

http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2012/11/19/installing-selenium-with-jenkins-on-ubuntu/

Cheers D